# function only works one time

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

This is my first question on here.  I use this site all of the time, but have never posted on here.

When I call the function writeMessage(), when the checkbox is checked, the textarea is created.  When I uncheck the checkbox, the textarea is removed.  When I check the checkbox the second time, the function is not called.  Any suggestions?  I need for it to show the textarea any time the checkbox is checked, not just the first time around.  Below is my code.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <th>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "os0" id = "spaceForMsg" onClick = "writeMessage()">
        <label for "gift"> Gift for someone</label> 
    </th>

</table>

<table >
    <tr id = 'parent'>
        <div id = 'printMsg'></div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

javascript function:

```
function writeMessage() {

    var x = document.getElementById('spaceForMsg');
    var docBody = document.getElementById('parent');
    var element = document.createElement('textarea');

    element.cols='60';
    element.rows='8';
    element.id = 'msgArea';

if (x.checked) {
    give = 'Type your gift message here: ';
    docBody.appendChild(element);

    } else {
        give = '';  
        y = document.getElementById('parent').parentNode;
        y.removeChild(y.childNodes[0]);

    }

    document.getElementById('printMsg').innerHTML = give;

}
```

Comment: As a side note, you probably only want to call `var element = document.createElement('textarea');` when you are actually planning on appending the node. Otherwise you are doing unnecessary work and making the garbage collector work more than it has to :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you just show and hide a textarea? that would be simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`writeMessage` is removing "the first child of the parent of `document.getElementById('parent')` (which happens to be equal to `docBody`). This means that you are removing `docBody` itself.

The next time you call `writeMessage` after removing `docBody`, the document will fail to find a proper `parent`, thus `docBody.appendChild(element);` will fail.

Try this instead:

```
function writeMessage() {
    var give;
    var x = document.getElementById('spaceForMsg');
    var docBody = document.getElementById('parent');

    if (x.checked) {
        var element = document.createElement('textarea');
        element.cols='60';
        element.rows='8';
        element.id = 'msgArea';
        give = 'Type your gift message here: ';
        docBody.appendChild(element);
    } else {
        give = '';  
        y = docBody.removeChild(docBody.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0]);
    }

    document.getElementById('printMsg').innerHTML = give;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing `<div id='parent'></div>`, with this line `y.removeChild(y.childNodes[0]);`, so you can't put anything in there since it doesn't exist.